# Get array of objects as result of comparing two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given 2 arrays of different length:

```js
const vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];
```

I need a new array containing the values in 'vals' that are in 'test' and their corresponding index as an object like

```js
result = [{1:"B"}, {3:"D"}, {4:"E"}, {7:"H"}]
```

Where `{1:"B"}` represents the object with index from the original array as key `1` and the matching value `B`

I got as far as

```js
const result = [vals, test];
result.reduce((a, b) => a.filter(c => b.includes(c)));
```

That yields `["B", "D", "E", "H"]` But I am struggling to get the index as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
const vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];


result = [...vals.entries()]
    .filter(e => test.includes(e[1]))
    .map(e => ({ [e[0]]: e[1] }))
  
console.log(result)
```

Here's a variation that computes indexes in both arrays and returns an array of triples `value, vals-index, test-index`, which you can convert as you please:

```js
const vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];


result = [...vals.entries()]
    .map(e => [e[1], e[0], test.indexOf(e[1])] )
    .filter(e => e[2] >= 0)
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I do like your answer but it does not return an array of objects, I guess I could accommodate

Comment: I tested both Nina's (which nail it the result) and your answer, and this one is more versatile to my needs

Comment: I have another question, what if I need to add the index of the test values as well, for example `{ "1": "B - 0" }, { "3": "D - 1" },` where 0 and 1 are the index of B and D respectively in the test array, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You could map with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
const
    vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"],
    test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"],
    result = test.map(v => ({ [vals.indexOf(v)]: v }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ok, but how about `test = [A B E H missing-val]`?

Comment: @georg, is that requested?

Answer (score 0):

The third argument to `reduce` is the index, so you could just do:

```js
const vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];

const result = vals.reduce((carry, current, index) => {
    if (test.includes(current)) {
        carry.push({[index]: current});
    }
    return carry;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out

```js
const vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];

const result=test.map(function(r){
  let i=vals.indexOf(r);
  let obj={};
  obj[i]=r;
  return obj;
})

console.log(result);
//result = [{1:"B"}, {3:"D"}, {4:"E"}, {7:"H"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `reduce` method

```
const vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];

let result = vals.reduce((acc,i, index) => { 
                                    let obj = {}; 
                                   if(test.includes(i)){
                                       obj[index]=i;
                                       acc.push(obj);
                                   }
               
                                   return acc;}, 
                             [])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

const ArrayOne = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
const ArrayTwo = ["B", "D", "E", "H"];

let result = ArrayOne.map((v, i) => [i, v]).filter(p => ArrayTwo.includes(p[1]))

console.log(result)

Then you can just convert the array into array of objects afterwards if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
  vals = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
  test = ["B", "D", "E", "H"]
  ans=list()
  k=0
  for i,j in enumerate(vals):
    if(k<len(test)):
       if(j==test[k]):
          ans.append({i,j})
           k=k+1
 print(ans)
```